# I am unable to type in my signup text field in some web browsers

Tags: javascript, php, html

my website http://404tools.com you can type in the sign up fields on  Firefox but not google chrome, opera, safari,and Microsoft edge. I am not sure what the problem is or even where it would be. Any help with this would be great this is the index.php below if you need any code please ask ill upload it.

```
 <?php
 session_start();
  include('inc/config.php');
  include('inc/functions.php');

  BlockIP();
 LoggedInTrue();
  ?>
<html>

<head>
  <title>    404Tools - Home</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://404tools.com    /favicon.ico" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"   media="screen" />
 </head>

 <body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="menu-header">
                <div id="title">
                        <span>404</span>Tools
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="menu-account">
                <div id="account-info">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>User</td>
                            <td><span>uriphere</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Level</td>
                            <td><span>admin</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="menu-menu">
                <div class="menu-news">
                    <h2 class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
                </div>

                <div id="menu-login">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="loginstrip" class="current"><a href="#" id="login">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <div id="dropdown">
                            <form method="POST">
                                <div id="dropdown-strip">
                                    <div id="dropdown-text">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div id="dropdown-strip">
                                    <div id="dropdown-text">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div id="dropdown-strip2">
                                    <div id="dropdown-text">
                                        <span id="loginbutton"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" /></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                                                </form>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-news">
        <div id="main-header">
            <div id="main-title">
                Please use the form below to register an account this process can take up to 24 hours if you don't receive an account by then either check your spam or fill out another request.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main-content-news">
            <a href="index.php">
                <div id="logo">
                    <IMG STYLE="text-align: center; TOP:30px; left:-1px;WIDTH:500px; HEIGHT:180px" SRC="new11.png" alt="">
            </a>

            </div>

            <div id="main-content-news">

            </div>
            <div id="box">
            </div>

            <div id="box-content">
                <br />
                <br />
                <div id="box-xeon">

                    <body>

                        <form method="POST">
                            <div id="dropdown-strip">
                                <div id="dropdown-text">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="dropdown-strip">
                                <div id="dropdown-text">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="dropdown-strip">
                                <div id="dropdown-text">
                                    <input type="password" name="repassword" placeholder="repassword" autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <table>
                                </tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>

                        <span style="padding: 5px;"><font color="#FFF">  </font><a href=""</a></span>

                    </body>
                    <div id="box-content">


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the content of `css/main.css` ? please update your question with it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zZvbHgJy  it was to large to format sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div id="box">` lays over the form elements:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

The `<table>` that exists in your `<form>` element has a `</tr>` as the first tag inside of it.  This should be changed to a `<tr>` and it will fix your problem.

Having `</tr>` before a `<tr>` basically means that you are closing a `table row` before you are opening it, which is breaking your HTML

[image: fix this here]

Comment: there is definitely a tag in there that is not being closed properly, I can tell by inspecting the element in chrome.  Go through each tag and make sure that all of them are being opened and closed properly.

Comment: If you use a good text editor like sublime or notepad++, it will allow you to click on the opening HTML tag and will underline the closing HTML tag.  This is the easiest way to make sure all of your tags are being properly closed.

Comment: i think I fixed it but now it wont center how do I fix that ?